# Confused with Eloquent relationship | Simple Phone Inventory Database

Tags: laravel, database-design, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

i'm confused creating Laravel Model classes for my database schema. How to create relationships?

The tables:

```
table_phone
    id
    imei
    model_id

table_model
    id
    name
    photo_id
    manufacturer_id

table_manufacturer
    id
    name
    photo_id
```

The Data Classes:

```
class Phone extends Model {

    function model() {

    }

}

class PhoneModel extends Model {

    function getPhones() {

    }

    function manufacturer() {

    }

}

class PhoneManufacturer extends Model {

    function getPhones() {

    }

    function getModels() {

    }
```

`Phone` class has one `PhoneModel` Class `(one-to-one)`.

`PhoneModel` class has one `PhoneManufacturer` Class `(one-to-one)`.

`PhoneManufacturer` class should have a method `getModels()`, which should return all `PhoneModel` class associated with the `manufacturer_id`.

`PhoneManufacturer` class should have a method `getPhones()`, which should return all `Phone` class associated with the `manufacturer_id` in the `PhoneModel` Class.

`PhoneModel` Class should have a method `getPhones()` which should return all `PhonePhone` class associated with the `model_id`.

`Phone` class should have `model` method and `manufacturer` method.
`PhoneModel` class should have `manufacturer` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create relationship in this way:

```php
class Phone extends Model {
    public function phonemodel()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(PhoneModel::class)
    }
}

class PhoneModel extends Model {
    public function phone()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Phone::class)
    }

    public function manufacturer()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Manufacturer::class)
    }
}

class Manufacturer extends Model {
    public function model()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(PhoneModel::class)
    }
}
```